# Custom html bullet points not showing, only normal bullet points show not the custom image i put in

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have put in custom CSS to ensure that a custom bullet point IMG is shown on my ul and li. The IMG isn't showing, only the default bullet point is showing and nothing I change is helping. It either causes everything to distort or nothing happens.

Please advise if you are able to.

Here is the code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  list-style-type:  !important;

} */



ul li {

  padding-left: 2rem;
  list-style-image: url(<img src="https://i.ibb.co/Tk59zVR/bullet-2.png" alt="bullet-2" border="0">);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 0

  
}
```

```html
 <p class="section-subtitle">
          <ul>
            <li>Savings on running costs/in-house labour costs</li>
            <li>Allows you to stay focused on your core-business without distractions. </li>

            <li>Reduce risk – government regulations non-compliance fines</li>

            <li>Level the playing field – get access to the similar technology and expertise that big companies enjoy
            </li>
          </ul>
          </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list-style-image` must be defined for `ul` and the `img` source was not used correcly.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  /*you probably do not need this*/
  /*list-style-type: !important;*/
  list-style-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/Tk59zVR/bullet-2.png");
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  /*you probably do not need this*/
  /*background-position: 0 0; */
  /*background-size: 0*/
}
```

```html
<p class="section-subtitle">
  <ul>
    <li>Savings on running costs/in-house labour costs</li>
    <li>Allows you to stay focused on your core-business without distractions. </li>

    <li>Reduce risk – government regulations non-compliance fines</li>

    <li>Level the playing field – get access to the similar technology and expertise that big companies enjoy
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

list-style-image should contain the path the image only. You are writing HTML in the list-style-image which is unknown to the browser.

You should use list-style-image like this:

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  list-style-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/Tk59zVR/bullet-2.png") !important;
}
```